# Get the following error while submitting a form: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /agents/create/ User has no userprofile

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm working on a project and get the following error: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /agents/create/
User has no userprofile.I created a form for the user to submit an Agent but when I create an Agent using the form it gives me the above mentioned error but when I try to submit an already created agent it says User with that name already exists.I have two apps Agents and Leads Here is my code:

agents/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from leads.models import Agent
from .forms import CreateAgentForm


class AgentListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'agents/agent_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Agent.objects.all()


class CreateAgentView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'agents/agent_create.html'
    form_class = CreateAgentForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('agent-list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        agent = form.save(commit=False)
        agent.userprofile = self.request.user.userprofile
        agent.save()
        return super(CreateAgentView, self).form_valid(form)
```

leads/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Lead(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    agent = models.ForeignKey('Agent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"


class Agent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name


def post_user_profile(instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(post_user_profile, sender=User)
```

agents/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import AgentListView, CreateAgentView



urlpatterns = [
    path('', AgentListView.as_view(), name='agent-list'),
    path('create/', CreateAgentView.as_view(), name='agent-create'),
]
```

agents/forms.py

```
from django import forms

from leads.models import Agent


class CreateAgentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Agent
        fields = ('user',)
```

I'm still learning so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you set up `leads.models.User` as `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py`?

Comment: Yes, I did set that when creating User model.

Answer (score 1):

I think the admin `user` has no user profile created, so you need to manually create one for him in the admin panel since migrations have already been done.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30284093)

Answer (score 0):

Erase your db and redo a migration.
Create User with the admin panel

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).